# How to find out package and theme name of our magento project?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I am facing difficulty in finding my package name and theme name in app/design/Frontend/ path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### From the root folder :

- Go to, your root folder
- app/design/frontend/default/  folder
- In this you can find the package or theme name.

### From the Admin panel :

- Login to your admin panel
- system-->configuration-->General-->Design
- In this you can find the package or theme name.

Comment: You most welcome Mr.Guru

Comment: In Root folder, you can edit the package name with your desired name, after that you need to replace package name with your desired name in admin also at about explained place.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the used template / package in the backend under `System > Configuration > Design`.

Also make sure it's used on the specific shop you're working on by switching the scope in the dropdown on the left.

[image]